# Waiting time until finished

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome

I know the title isn't very descriptive, and that's because I don't know the why to this pseudo-problem.

I have a website in php that makes queries to different databases and show the results in a table.
That is working just fine.

My "problem" is that when a query is being processed and the browser is showing the loader icon if i open a second tab it wont load until the first is finished.

I really need to avoid this, but I don't know where the restriction is. Is it something that the browser does?
Two tabs in google chrome wont work, neither two tabs in safari. But the same page opened in both browsers works just fine and there is no "waiting until finished".

Thanks in advance for your help, im really lost here.

Comment: You're probably blocking on session.  Don't use session.

Comment: session as in php sessions? $_SESSION? @SLaks

Comment: `session_write_close();`

Comment: That was it! Thanks!